# How to unwrap an observable in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Following is a behaviour subject with initial value as observable.

```
items$ = new BehaviourSubject(this.getItems())

getItems() {
return of(...some value)
}
```

But the above method is not working. Seems like we cannot pass an observable in to a behaviour subject. Is there a way to unwrap observable and pass it to the behaviour subject?

I'm doing this because I need a way to modify observable value. (ie. though the `getItems()` values are fired by the backend, I need a way to push some values from the client side also without disturbing the original `getItems()` )

Comment: your getItems() coming from backend api ?

Answer (score 1):

The general pattern to initialize a `behaviurSubject` automatically is to use one of Angular's lifecycle hooks (Since I see you used the angular tag).

```
items$ = new BehaviourSubject<Item>(null);

ngOnInit(){
  this.getItems().subscribe(x => items$.next(x));
}

getItems() {
  return of(...some value)
}
```

If instead, you want future calls to getItems to update the `behaviurSubject`, you can do this:

```
items$ = new BehaviourSubject<Item>(null);

ngOnInit(){
  this.getItems().subscibe();
}

getItems() {
  return of(...some value).pipe(
    tap(x => items$.next(x))
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you try to address in the wrong way, I mean you could pass it the value instead of an observable. Also in the BehaviorSubject you could pass a empty array and then you could request to the API and subscribe to the observable an pass the value. But also you could try to explain you are trying to it in this way

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the Behaviorsubject as a subscriber.

```
items$ = new BehaviourSubject(null)
this.getItems.subscribe(this.items$);
```